# Python post request doesn't send the data

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm trying to execute the following function:

```
    def create_report(self):
        url = "<some_url>"
        headers = self.head_auth
        post_data = {"startDate": "2024-01-24T10:30:18.276+02:00", "endDate": "2024-01-25T10:30:18.276+02:00",
                     "headers": ["event_date"], "filters": [], "parametersData": {}, "outputType": 1,
                     "reportTimeZone": "UTC+0", "isCustom": True, "reportName": "delete", "metrics": ["imp"],
                     "minimumImpressionsThreshold": None}
        json_data = json.dumps(post_data)
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json_data)
        return json.loads(response.text)
```

but i'm getting an error that the payload is empty,
Does anyone can think about the reason?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Also, include the full error message that is produced then. That should answer the question whether it's a response from the remote side or a locally generated fault.

Comment: Did you try, 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=post_data)

    return response.json()

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_report(self):
    url = "<some_url>"
    headers = self.head_auth
    post_data = {"startDate": "2024-01-24T10:30:18.276+02:00", "endDate": "2024-01-25T10:30:18.276+02:00",
                 "headers": ["event_date"], "filters": [], "parametersData": {}, "outputType": 1,
                 "reportTimeZone": "UTC+0", "isCustom": True, "reportName": "delete", "metrics": ["imp"],
                 "minimumImpressionsThreshold": None}
    #json_data = json.dumps(post_data)
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_data)
    #return json.loads(response.text)
    return response.json()
```

No need for dumping it as it will convert it into json binary object and this needs to passed as dictionary as the requests library will take care of changing and sending part. Also you can trim down the steps by changing `json.loads(response.text)` to `response.json()` simply